# How to delete row for group avg() lower than x?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  user_id     canon_id           score
| 28772984 | 28772984 |             .1 |
| 28773001 | 28772088 |             .1 |
| 28773011 | 28773011 |              1 |
| 28773046 | 28773011 |             .4 |
| 28773069 | 28773011 |             .1 |
| 28773077 | 28773077 |              1 |
| 28773072 | 28773077 |             .1 |
```

In this case how do I delete canon_id's whose average(score) is smaller than 0.50?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a delete with join

```
    delete m
    from my_table m 
    inner join  (
        select canon_id
        from my_table  
        group by canon_id 
        having avg(score)<0.5
    ) t on t.canon_id = m.canon_id
```